# Efficient way to find lowest divisor of an integer.

Tags: reference-request, divisibility, factoring

I have followed the given way to find the lowest divisor of an integer,

Let us assume `n` is the given integer.

- *Check `n` is divisible by `2`,*
- *If yes then `2` will be the lowest divisor*
- *else Get the square root of `n`.*
- *Divide the value of n with (`3` to `< square root(n)`) if any value divides the `n` in that particular range. Then that will be the the

  lowest divisor. If nothing divides, then `n` is a prime number.*

Is there any other efficient mathematical way available to simplify this process.? Links regarding the efficient ways are welcome.

Comment: Just a comment that you might not found a fully satisfying answer.  Note that if there were such an efficient algorithm, it would have to be at least as inefficient as determining if a number is prime.  Having said that, it's certainly possible to do better than your suggestion.  Maybe start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @Callus Well, a sieve isn't really going to help if OP is going to end up only bothering with one value of `n`. Agreed with the rest of what you said though.

Comment: I guess I was thinking to use the sieve to eliminate possible divisors, eg. avoid checking if $4$ is a divisor if you've already confirmed $2$ is not a divisor.  Pretty bad worst case, though.  Waste of time for something like $3$ to a large power!

Comment: Note that this algorithm **fails** by erroneously declaring squares of primes to be prime because the upper limit of the loop is not $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$, i.e. for n=25 it would trial-divide only by 3 and 4.

Comment: An excellent treatment of this can be found in *The Haskell Road to Maths, Logic, and Programming* 2nd ed. by Doets and van Eijck. It's the very first discussion chapter 1.

Answer (score 1):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

For example, in nearly every situation where I had to write code to sort an array of numbers, bubble sort was by far the most efficient implementation... because the time my program would save using a 'more efficient' sort, even when added up over all the times my program would ever be run, would be several orders of magnitude less than the time I would waste coding up a more complicated sort.

If you truly are in a situation where the act of asking your question on MSE is not already many orders of magnitude slower than simply using the simple algorithm you described, then, most likely, you are going to want to use one of the standard integer factoring algorithms (e.g. "pollard rho") to factor your number.

That said, an extremely simple optimization to the program you suggested is to only test the odd divisors in the last step, since you already know $2$ isn't a divisor.